# Wordpress Questions plugins: Questions not found!

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am currently constructing a wordpress website with a page that allows questions to be asked. However, when the question is asked, the page for that particular question can not be found.

I have tried different question and answer plugins and i have had the same problems. Clicking on the question (or on the link that says "All Questions") takes me to an error page that says "this page can not be found".

Normally the questions page from the plugin uses the single.php template file.

I dont know if anyone else has done this before or has had this problem before. I am currently testing the wprdpress site on my machine so i am not able to provide u with a link.

I hope someone can help me with this even though i understand that the information ive given is quite limited.

Thanks in advance

ps, the plugin website is: http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/qa-wordpress-questions-and-answers-plugin-lite

Comment: This is too little info.  I think you should contact the author of the plug-in.

Comment: apparently i need to subscribe for $75 to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using the free light version of the plugin you should directly ask the plugin author on the [WordPress.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/tags/qa?forum_id=10).

A lot of users feel this plugin is a [blatant Stackoverflow rip off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88870/wordpress-qa-plugin-blatently-ripping-off-stack-overflow-design) so your likely not going to get much help here.

Comment: perfect. found my answer on the link u sent. CHEERS!!